# jQuery cookie control

Tags: jquery, cookies

How to create cookie, which will work **on all pages over choosen site**?

Using [cookie plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/cookie).

Code must add cookie "movie_check" with value "no", which can be used over all pages on site "www.site.com" (were script is implemented). Expires after 365 days.

Tryed this (doesnt work):

```
$.cookie("movie_check", "no", {expires: 365, domain: 'www.site.com'});
```

Thanks.

Comment: What are you anticipating to happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
 var date = new Date();
 date.setTime(date.getTime() + (3 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
$.cookie('movie_check', 'no', { path: '/', expires: date });
```

Your code sets an expiration date in the past.

Comment: what value gives date variable?

Comment: don't we need to add "domain" value ?

Comment: Date gives it a time 3 days into the future. Domain is automatically assumed to be the domain you are setting the cookie on.

Comment: If you pass a Number, it [means](http://plugins.jquery.com/files/jquery.cookie.js.txt) number of days in the future.  So the original expires should be fine.